# Convert string to dictionary in R

Tags: r, string, dictionary

I have a data frame column with dictionary-like strings.

```
data = data.frame(date = c('2022-12-01', '2022-12-02'), 
           code = c("{\"551\":4,\"181\":4,\"180\":4,\"181\":4}",
                    "{\"321\":14,\"181\":4,\"230\":4,\"189\":12}"))
```

My goal is to calculate the total number if the "dictionary" starts with `18`.

For example, first row `2022-12-01`, there are three items start with `18`, so the total number is `4+4+4 =12`.
For second row `2022-12-02`, there are two items start with `18`, so the total number is `4+4+12=16`.

I tried `strsplit(data$code, "\\W")`, which split on every delimiter; or `strsplit(data$code, ",")`, but fail to store it as a dictionary-type structure.

I feel that after converting the string to a dictionary, then filter on names starts with `18` would be feasible, but have no idea how to get started. Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are several approaches.  The first uses `strapply` and is particularly short.  The next shows how to create a dictionary using `strapply` and the last uses only base R.

In all of these use `transform(data, sum = ...)` or use `mutate` in dplyr to add the solution as a new column to `data`.

**1)** Match the number after an 18 and then convert the match to numeric and sum.  Using `strapply` we get particularly concise code.

```
library(gsubfn)

sapply(strapply(data$code, '"18\\d+":(\\d+)', as.numeric), sum)
## [1] 12 16
```

**2)** In the question the desirability of creating a dictionary first was mentioned.  To do that `dict` below is a list of dictionaries, one per row, and then we grep out the desired elements and sum.

```
library(gsubfn)

dict <- strapply(data$code, '"(\\d+)":(\\d+)', x + y ~ setNames(as.numeric(y), x))
sapply(lapply(dict, function(x) x[grepl("^18", names(x))]), sum)
## [1] 12 16

dict
## [[1]]
## 551 181 180 181 
##   4   4   4   4 
##
## [[2]]
## 321 181 230 189 
##  14   4   4  12
```

**3)** A base solution replaces the {, } and comma characters with newline and then for each row reads the rest into two columns (the dictionary).  It then subsets out the rows that begin with 18 and sums.

```
sapply(data$code, function(x) 
       gsub('[{},]', '\n', x) |> 
       read.table(text = _, sep = ":") |>
       subset(grepl("^18", V1)) |>
       with(sum(V2)), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
## [1] 12 16
```

If you just want that part of the code that constructs the dictionaries

```
lapply(data$code, function(x) 
       gsub('[{},]', '\n', x) |> 
       read.table(text = _, sep = ":"))
## [[1]]
##    V1 V2
## 1 551  4
## 2 181  4
## 3 180  4
## 4 181  4
## 
## [[2]]
##    V1 V2
## 1 321 14
## 2 181  4
## 3 230  4
## 4 189 12
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
data = data.frame(date = c('2022-12-01', '2022-12-02'), 
           code = c("{\"551\":4,\"181\":4,\"180\":4,\"181\":4}",
                    "{\"321\":14,\"181\":4,\"230\":4,\"189\":12}"))

data$count <- lapply(data$code,jsonlite::fromJSON) |> sapply(
  \(x) sum(unlist(x)[grep("^18", names(x))]) )

data
#>         date                                code count
#> 1 2022-12-01   {"551":4,"181":4,"180":4,"181":4}    12
#> 2 2022-12-02 {"321":14,"181":4,"230":4,"189":12}    16
```

Answer (score 1):

I would first make a data.frame where each row is a {name, value} pair. I do this by first separating the pairs onto rows, then separating the name and value into separate columns. Then I parse the text to keep only the numbers. Finally we summarise the table by date, taking the sum of those values for which the name starts with "18".

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  separate_rows(code, sep = ',') %>% 
  separate(code, sep = '":', into = c('name', 'value')) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(name, value), parse_number)) %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  summarise(result = sum(value[substr(name, 1, 2) == "18"]))
```

Answer (score 1):

A **base R** approach using `strsplit` and `sub`/`gsub`.

First remove the braces and quotes, then look for strings starting with `^` 18 and finally `sum` the trailing numbers after `:`.

```
cbind(df, Sum = sapply(strsplit(df$code, ","), function(x) 
  sum(as.numeric(
    sub(".*:", "", grep("^18", gsub("\\{|\"|\\}", "", x), value=T)))
)))
        date                                code Sum
1 2022-12-01   {"551":4,"181":4,"180":4,"181":4}  12
2 2022-12-02 {"321":14,"181":4,"230":4,"189":12}  16
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R`

```
data$Sum <-  sapply(regmatches(data$code, gregexpr('(?<=18\\d":)(\\d+)', 
     data$code, perl = TRUE)), \(x) sum(as.numeric(x)))
data$Sum
[1] 12 16
```